# Problem running Tor under Ubuntu

Tags: configuration, ubuntu

I followed the [instructions to install Tor in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en).

When I invoke Tor from the command line it proceeds to the point that I'm told that it has bootstrapped 100% and a circuit is established.  But then I keep getting the warning,

> Got a certificate for ides, but we already have it.  Maybe they haven't updated it.  Waiting for a while.

and it loops forever.

I am also warned that I have an old version of Tor, 0.2.2.25, although my understanding is that the correct version should have been installed.  Doc says that `apt-get update` will fix my problem but it seems to do so.  Not Good.  In the end I don't care what flavor of *nix I run since I won't use the machine for anything but for running the relay currently on my other machine, but I heard Ubuntu is easy to use.

My `torrc` is vanilla except for changing `SocksPort`  to 9053 so that it wouldn't collide w / my  relay running on another machine.

1. How to I get Tor to boot successfully ?
2. How do I get the latest version?

This is but my second day of using *nix, so be gentle and detailed  w/ me.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the packages from Ubuntu repository as the [Debian/Ubuntu Instructions page](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en) (also linked above :) explains:

> Do not use the packages in Ubuntu's universe. In the past they have not reliably been updated. That means you could be missing stability and security fixes.

You just need to go to the [download page](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en) and select GNU/Linux[..] option. Tor Browser Bundle will come with an up-to-date version of Tor.

Comment: https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-unix.html.en says,  "If you're using Ubuntu, don't use the default packages: use our deb repository (https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#ubuntu) instead, which is what I did.

This seemed to be reinforced by Roger D.'s answer 9/28/13 to a similar Ubuntu-related question.
Your answer was spot-on, thank you.  Perhaps the documentation isn't clear on this installation point.

Just a thought.

P

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.04 ships [Tor 0.2.2.35-1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/tor) at the moment. Assuming you made a typo (25 instead of 35) it seems you have installed this version. Open a terminal and enter `apt-cache policy tor`. Now you'll see what version is installed and if there is maybe an update.

If you don't see a newer version of Tor check the steps at the [instruction page](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en). Make sure to have the line

```
deb     http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org precise main
```

in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or the file where you keep this information. Furthermore it is important to execute an `apt-get update`. Only after this step `apt` is able to find the new version of Tor.